# Free Japanese Grammar Material

Tags: discussion, resources

I self-study Japanese. I am at JLPT N3 Level (if we will base it on the certificate that I have). However, I really think I'm weak with grammar. I mostly understand when someone speaks Japanese, but I am having a hard time choosing the right term. I mostly struggle with verb tenses and many other things about grammar. Can somebody recommend me any free online material where I can easily learn and practice (preferably one that really starts with the basic rules)

I'm not just so into language app full of just quizzes, I really want
a material with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.guidetojapanese.org/grammar_guide.pdf
(Tae Kim's grammer guide)

https://wildnihongo.com/
A website on Japanese grammer

These are two resources I have for you; they are free to use and download, and rest assured no copyright violations will take place if you use them.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learnjapanesedaily.com/jlpt-n3-grammar) website lists grammar lessons at the JLPT N3 level. It's more of a list of grammar structures, but it des help.

[Here](https://japanesetest4you.com/jlpt-n3-grammar-list/) is a list of grammar rules at the N3 level. A quick glance over this might help you as well. You can click each structure for more details, making it similar to a textbook.